# Is it possible to configure dkim signing outgoing emails with msmtp?

Tags: dkim, msmtp

Is it possible just install opendkim, generate keys, and specify some options for msmtp to automatically send dkim-signed email?

My server (Ubuntu 20.04) uses msmtp-mta with following config.

```
defaults
auth on
tls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
logfile /var/log/msmtp

account default
host smtp.someprovider.com
port 587
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck off
from no-reply@example.info
user no-reply@example.info
password somepasswort
```

1. msmtp man page doesn't have any appropriate options for dkim. (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/msmtp.1.html)
2. there was similar questions, but without details in answer
   [Validation for local DKIM signature fails after sending through msmtp](https://superuser.com/questions/1702417/validation-for-local-dkim-signature-fails-after-sending-through-msmtp)
3. should I better use postfix for this?